# Microsoft graph user delta - manager issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I try to get users via the delta endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$select=id,displayName,manager
```

The returned response will contain some users with the manager property defined, as expected:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(id,displayName,manager)",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$skiptoken=[token]",
    "value": [
        {
            "displayName": "user1",
            "id": "id1"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "user2",
            "id": "id2",
            "manager@delta": [
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                    "id": "managerId1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "user3",
            "id": "id3"
        },
        // etc
    ]
}
```

However when I then query the returned `nextLink` to get the second page, the **same set of users** are returned as the first page, and this time without any managers. Also note that the `@odata.context` value has changed now too:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$skiptoken=[token]",
    "value": [
        {
            "displayName": "user1",
            "id": "id1"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "user2",
            "id": "id2"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "user3",
            "id": "id3"
        },
        ... etc
    ]
}
```

When I remove the `displayName` property, so am only selecting for `id` and `manager`, the paging seems to work correctly:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$select=id,manager
```

The issue has been reproduced when including the `userPrincipalName` property in the `$select` too.

Comment: Hi @petero, What is the difference between the output you have noticed.

Comment: Response from <https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$select=id,displayName,manager>
{
 "displayName": "peteroUser",
 "id": "875bd72d-874e-40ee-b0aa-00ab6d8883ca",
 "manager@delta": [
  {
   "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
   "id": "333f5b8d-9932-4d7b-a2fd-babde49655f5"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: Response from next link
{
 "displayName": "peteroUser",
 "id": "875bd72d-874e-40ee-b0aa-00ab6d8883ca"
}

Comment: You can see, same user returned, first with manager, second one without manager

Comment: When I request user properties without manager, user delta works fine.

Comment: I am confused,First one is showing manager but second one is not showing manager but both are calling same user.I tested in my environment and unable to reproduce.Please let me know if there are any reproduction steps.

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity the issue is with the second call - it is using the nextLink value to retrieve the second page of data. The response returns the same users from the first page, and on top of that it will also lose the `manager` property. You may have difficulties reproducing this if your test environment does not have enough users to generate multi-page responses